# Android 6.0 notification bar and quick setting drop down menu not working.

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-bar, quick-settings

My phone was working fine, and i didn't run any updates prior to this issue.

The pull down menu is no longer working properly. I can pull it down, so that it shows the time and date, signal and battery. But the rest isn't working, i can't pull it down further to get to settings, not do i see any notifications. Instead it just showed ' No Notifications'  even if i actually receive messages or emails.

I tried recovered trough fastboost, but i'd rather not try a factory reset unless there are no other options.

Comment: May I know your device model?

Comment: Htc One M8, running around 6.0.

Answer (score -1):

Performed a hard factory reset. Didn't want too, but it's fixed now.